# Get the head or everything but the head of a slice

Tags: go, go-templates

How do I get the head or tail of a slice in Go template?
What I would like to use:

```
{{template "breadcrumb" $urlArray[0] $urlArray[1:]}}
```

Comment: Remove it from the slice before you send it to the template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get slice element by using `index`:

```
{{ $length := len $urlArray }}
first - {{index $urlArray 0}}
```

But it's more difficult with the last, since you have to get index `$length - 1`, and arithmetic operations are not allowed in templates.

But you can expose go functions to templates:

```
func first(s []string) string {
  if len(s) == 0 {
    return ""
  }
  return s[0]
}

func last(s []string) string {
  if len(s) == 0 {
    return ""
  }
  return s[len(s) - 1]
}

const tmpl = `first - {{ first $urlArray }}, last - {{ last $urlArray }}`

t := template.Must(template.New("").Funcs(template.FuncMap{"first": first, "last": last}).Parse(tmpl))
```